# When debugging, Is there an Option to not focus Terminal automatically?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

There are times I just need to keep my focus on the **Watch** panel as I debug.

What keeps happening is as soon as I start start a fresh debugging session(`Run` > `Start Debugging`), foc
us is given to the terminal.

see this example:

[image: example]

This is completely throwing my focus of and forces my hand to the mouse as well.

Is there a way I can turn it of?

PS:This seems to be powershell specific, it does not happen with other languages I use, such as Autohotkey.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a very common thing to do, and very well documented in the docs and all over the web/Youtube. What did you search for? ['Using VSCode, how always to keep focus on the editor pane?'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27Using+VSCode%2C+how+to+always+keep+focus+on+the+editor+pane%3F+%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a setting in your VSCode config (User/Workspace settings).

```
"powershell.integratedConsole.focusConsoleOnExecute": false
```

See the blog for a conversation about what you are after if you don't want to dig thru the docs.

> How to customize Visual Studio (VS) Code for PowerShell
>
> https://www.pdq.com/blog/customizing-visual-studio-code-for-powershell/

The same detail is in the docs as well.

Just add the line, restart VSC and you should get what you are after.

Know, this does work in VSC with either WinPS/PSCore shell.
Yet, I am on Windows, not Mac.